# How to calculate and plot a 95% confidence interval in R

Tags: confidence-interval

I am using the following R Code to calculate a "Lowess" smooth line for a data set. I then need to add a 95% confidence line that would be associated with my smooth line.

```
 plot(seq,count)  #Plots the data

 y.loess <- loess(y ~ x, span=0.8, data.frame(x=seq, y=count))  # Apply loess smoothing using the default span value of 0.8

 y.predict <- predict(y.loess, data.frame(x=seq))  # Compute loess smoothed values for all points along the curve

 lines(seq,y.predict)  # Plot the curve.
```

How do I add, plot, and grey fill a confidence interval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the following statement:

loess() is a fitting algorithm, so no parameters are estimated and no 
*confidence* intervals nor bands can be produced.

If you are interested in *prediction* interval, it can be done with *ggplot* (described here).

(from [R help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confidence-bands-around-LOESS-td4639521.html))

Comment: That's it - thanks.  Would you know what parameter I would set to fill the interval with a solid grey background.

Comment: @Jeff if I am right, you should do smth like https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-July/168230.html . Or is the question about how to calculate prediction interval manually? I guess it is just a sample quantiles and done with smth like quantile loess regression.

Comment: Filling the area between the interval

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- 1:500
b <- rnorm(500, 50, 50)
df <- data.frame(a, b)
ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b)) + geom_smooth(method="loess")
```

produces:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote a function doing that for Bernoulli random variables. If it can helps, feel free to use/change it !

```
bernoulli.confint <- function(x = NULL, y, n = NULL, conf.level = 0.95, rgb = c(255,210,0)) {
  if(is.matrix(y) || is.data.frame(y)) {
    df <- data.frame(sucess = y[,1],
                     failures = y[,2],
                     total = y[,1] + y[,2])
  } else {
    if(is.null(n)) {
      stop("Either y is a vector of (sucess, failures) and n is NULL, or n is not null.")
    } else {
      df <- data.frame(sucess = y,
                       failures = n - y,
                       total = n)
    }
  }

  if(is.null(x)) {
    x <- 1:length(sucess)
  }
  df$x <- x
      df <- df[order(df$x),]

  df$lower <- NA
      df$upper <- NA
  df$estimate <- NA
      for(r in 1:nrow(df)) {
        test <- binom.test(df$sucess[r], df$total[r], 0, conf.level = conf.level)
        df$lower[r] <- test$conf.int[1]
        df$upper[r] <- test$conf.int[2]
        df$estimate[r] <- test$estimate
  }

  plot(df$x, df$estimate, type = "l", col = rgb(rgb[1],rgb[2],rgb[3], maxColorValue = 255))
  polygon(c(df$x, rev(df$x)),
          c(df$lower, rev(df$upper)), 
          col = rgb(rgb[1],rgb[2],rgb[3], alpha = 50, maxColorValue = 255), border = NA)
}
```